# How to create dynamic form fields from schemas

Tags: python, json, django, forms, dynamic

I'm trying to make a JSON Creator form that is dynamically created based off of a schema chosen by the user.  I made an example of how I would want one to more or less look like.

Take this given schema:

```
{
    "type":"object"
    "properties":
        "color": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["red","green","blue"]
        },
        "unique_id": {
            "type": "string"
            "maxLength": 15 
        },
        "workload":{
            "type": "object",
            "properties":{
                "write_pre":{
                    "type": "number",
                    "minimum": -1
                },
                "read_pre":{
                    "type": "number",
                    "minimum": -1
                },
                "required": ["write_pre","read_pre"],
                "additionalProperties": false
            }
        },
        "required": ["color", "unique_id"],
        "additionalProperties": false
}
```

I would want my form to look something like this:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/background.css" %}">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="navbar">
      </div>
        <h1>Welcome To The JSONCreator</h1>
        <form method="post" class="creator">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <h4>color: *required</h4>
                <select name="color" required>
                  <option value="red">red</option>
                  <option value="green">green</option>
                  <option value="blue">blue</option>
                </select>
          <h4>unique_id: *required</h4>
            <input type="text" name="unique_id" required>
          <h4>workload:</h4>
            <h5>work_pre: *required</h5>
              <input type="number" min="-1" name="workloadWork_pre" required>
            <h5>read_pre: *required</h5>
              <input type="number" min="-1" name="workloadRead_pre" required>
          <br><br><input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is I don't know how I would auto update the form fields to the given property fields given in the schema.  I'm planning not to actually write the form with Django's form and not in HTML. I just used HTML in this example as a really quick mock-up to give my question more context.

I'm using Python2.7 and Django 1.11 and no database

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/django-jsonforms/

Comment: @user2896976 Do you have the readthedocs link for it? I'm trying to understand this package better. More specifically I'm trying to see if and how it can take in user input from the previous page to update the form and its fields.

Comment: @user2896976 Is there anywhere that there is a full example using this package with what the output looks like?  This package looks promising, like it would solve so many problems, but I would like to see an example with an output so I know what I'm getting myself into before downloading it.